# Android Bitmap OutOfMemory issue

Tags: android

My application would have more than 350 images which would be decoded from database. I create bitmap from image data and scale them based on device screen resolution. When I tried to hold all of these bitmaps into memory, I was facing outOfMemory exception. Then BitmapFactory.Options.inPurgeable has been recommended in various places as a way to avoid OutOfMemoryExceptions.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inInputShareable = true;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagaeData, 0, size, options);
...
..
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, reqWidth, reqHeight, true);
```

I am caching this scaled bitmap to HashMap and using it for image view. Again I am facing OutOfMemory exception while loading the bitmaps to memory. I don't understnad whether the inPurgeable is working in my case. I am wondering will the scaled bitmap have reference to bytes array. As I am using scaled bitmap, will it have the effect of the inPurgeable option used in decodeByteArray. I am not able to figure out how to handle this bitmap memory issue. Appreciate your help.

Comment: in BitmapFactory.Options you can already specify a scaling

Comment: I want to scale up or down based on my own defined scale factor. For example If my created bitmap size is 50 X 50 and my scaling factor is 2.0, I want to scale up the bitmap to size of 100 X 100. Can that be done using BitmapFactory.Options?

Comment: not exactly. Options contain a downsampling param. Usually, you'll open your bitmap in size mode to obtain only the size, then measure a scale factor to have a downsampled image, then use this to reopen the image in default mode, then use this image in createScaledBitmap.

Comment: Yeah. I understand what you are telling. Using inSampleSize options, downsampling is possible and it should be power of 2. Here I want to scale up or down to any size calculated with my scale factor.

Comment: PS Don't forget to upvote/accept if any of the answers were helpful

Answer (score 0):

350 images are quite a lot. Are you sure that you need them all at once?

Also: as you create a scaled bitmap, you have them in memory twice -> 700 images in memory is way way way too much. You should check if it would be better to use `inScale` on the option to reduce it to 350 again plus reduce the memory footprint.

I still think that even in optimized ways 350 images are just too much. You should consider a lazy loading solution.

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I use inScaled option to scale bitmap from size 50 X 50 to 75 X 75. I am not aware of this option. Appreciate your help if you could provide any example code.

Answer (score 0):

You may try BitmapFactory.Options.inScaled & BitmapFactory.Options. inScreenDensity to get the scaled bitmap.

And you need a better way to cache bitmap in memory. You'd better hold WeakReference of the Bitmap in HashMap for the bitmap, and you can switch to LinkedHashMap for a simple LRU cache implementation.

You don't really need cache all the images, since they'll never get a chance to be displayed in one screen.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it sounds crazy to try and keep 350 bitmaps in memory at once. Even if they were small I wouldn't recommend it. Surely you won't be able to show all these bitmaps at once, so whats the point of keeping all of them in memory at the same time?

You really should look into using something like [Square's Picasso lib](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for handling image loading and scaling. Picasso handles "ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter", "automatic memory and disk caching" and finally also "complex image transformations with minimal memory use".

Comment: I really didn't want to hold all 350 bitmaps in memory. I was doing Disck Cache initially. Later I got to know about inPurgeable option to handle out of memory issue. As I am using disk caching, there is a delay in fetching bitmap and loading it to image view. There was perfromance issue. But When I have all images in RAM, there is no delay in loading the bitmap to image view. This is the reason I am looking to hold all bitmaps into memory to reduce latency in loading the bitmap to imageview.

Comment: I think the widely accepted lazy loading of images as you scroll through a long list/grid of images is enough, isn't it? Think of the way the default camera gallery loads images. It works well and there's no risk of running into oom issues. As long as you load using an asynctask, Picasso or similar solution the app will still feel snappy and responsive.

Comment: Thanks britzl. It makes sense. I wanted to ensure if there is any best method to hold bitmap efficiently in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to reduce the image size first (file points to a photo on SD card)

```
//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
        stream1.close();

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        // maximum size is 50
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=40;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<=REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<=REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
        stream2.close();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

// Here is how to call the above method

```
                    String path = "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/camera/IMG_2001.jpg";
                    Drawable background = hash_map.get(path);
                    if (background == null) {
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(new File(path));
                        background = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                        if (hash_map.size() > 600) {
                            // to prevent HashMap from growing too large.
                            hash_map.clear();
                        }
                        hash_map.put(path, background);
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        // in case there is an exception, like running out of memory.
                        if (e instanceof OutOfMemoryError) {
                            hash_map.clear();
                        }
                    }
                 }
```